# Socket problem - readline won't work properly

Tags: java, sockets

I try to code a client and server connection using socket. The problem is my client can't read the response from the server (it hangs on the readline).

Here is some of the code.

#### Server:

```
    try {
        // Create the server socket.
        portNumber = Integer.parseInt(myParam.get("socket.portNumber"));
        System.out.println(portNumber);
        mainSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error Message : "+ioe.getMessage());
    }

    while(true)
    {     
        try
        {
            // Accept connections
            Socket clientSocket = mainSocket.accept();
            SocketServerThread st = new SocketServerThread (clientSocket);
            st.start();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Error message :"+ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

#### The Thread:

```
public void run() {

    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    String clientResponse = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        //Read The Message
        String clientRequest = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message recieved : " + clientRequest);

        //Process the message

        // Send response
        out.println(clientResponse+"\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Clean up
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

#### The client:

```
    try {
        // Create the server socket.
        simSocket = new Socket("192.168.52.27", portNumber);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error Message : " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(simSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(simSocket.getOutputStream()));

            out.write("My message");
            out.flush();

            do{
            response = in.readLine(); //This is where the code hang
            }while (response.length()<= 0);

            System.out.print(response);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error message :" + ioe.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            simSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Could you guys tell me what's the problem? Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Did you ping and check your sever and client is whether reachable ?

Comment: Are you getting "Message received" in the server? Also, are you sure you're not hanging in the server before you answer? And why are you using a loop?

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh All the program are running in a local network so I'm sure that the client can contact the server.

Comment: @Robert I'm sure that I got the message received, I even already processed the message (Before I hardcode the reply). And for why I'm using loop...let say I'm an idiot that make a very big mistake (I already remove it in the new code...I hope)

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I've figured this one out. It's not the client that hangs, it's the server. It tries to read a line of text from the client, but the client doesn't send the line separator:

```
    out.write("My message");
    out.flush();
```

Replace write() with println() here.

Comment: well when I debug it, it enter the server, go to the tread, process the message then send it...after that it stop in readline (client) so I assumed that is where the problem is.I love to try your solution but since I already change the code, and I feel extremely lazy to turn it back... D:

Comment: Strange. I have tested it and in my case it didn't go past readLine() in the server. Maybe you did it with another version of your code, not the one posted here.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I made several editing in the code and now it run nicely :

The server :

```
    try {
        // Create the server socket.
        portNumber = Integer.parseInt(myParam.get("socket.portNumber"));
        mainSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error Message : " + ioe.getMessage());
    }

    // Accept connections    
    try {
        clientSocket = mainSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error Message : " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            //Read The Message
            **StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (true) {
                int ch = in.read();
                if ((ch < 0) || (ch == '\n')) {
                    break;
                }
                buffer.append((char) ch);
            }
            String clientRequest = buffer.toString();**

            SocketServerThread st = new SocketServerThread(clientRequest, out);
            st.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept connection. Error message :" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I change the readline with read and it work, so the assumption that "\n" is the problem is correct.

The thread :
a minor change in the thread (remove the reading request part since I already done that in the server)

The Client:
change the readline into read just like the server one.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: I had a similar problem in that inputstreap.readline was working for the header lines of a http request, but had to use read (char by char) in order to detect end of line on the content part. Did like this: int read;
            while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) read);
                
                //extra check
                if (stringBuilder.length() == contentLength){
                    break;
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
out.write("My message");
```

That doesn't send a line terminator so it can never be read. Use println().

```
out.println(clientResponse+"\n");
```

That will send the clientResponse plus a newline plus a \n. The last part will probably be interpreted as a blank line. Not much point in that. Remove the \n.

```
do{
    response = in.readLine(); //This is where the code hang
}while (response.length()<= 0);
```

That's not the correct way to read lines. It will get an NPE at EOS; the response length can never be negative; and why would you send yourself blank lines? The correct way is this:

```
while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // if (response.length() == 0) continue; // if you must
    // process the line
}
// when you get here EOS has occurred.
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it be because `clientResponse` (sent by server thread) is `null` and the client is waiting for response size > 0?

Comment: Ra2huram Nope,I even try hard code the clientResponse (bypass all the message processing) and still hang

Comment: @Willy How about adding "\n" to the message in the client, i.e. out.write("My message\n");

Comment: Still not working.I try adding \n \r \r\n. None of them work >.<

Comment: The only way it can be null is if the peer closed the connection, which would not cause `readLine()` to block.

Answer (score -1):

According to the javaDoc, the server response actually is

```
"My Message:\n"+System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

I bet, `in.readLine()` works fine at least once - but you just ignore the response, because the print command is outside the loop. Move that one up, and you should see the responses on the console.

There is a (very small) chance, that the servers `println()` doesn't really send a `\n` char. So you could try this at the thread code:

```
 out.print(clientResponse+"\n\n");  // exchanged println with an extra \n char
```

Comment: Neither seems to be true to me. If `in.readLine()` returned a non-empty string at least once, it would break the loop and the response would be printed. And I see no reason why `println()` wouldn't send the line separator.

Comment: @Sergey - the reason for `println()` is given in the JavaDoc. It will send whatever is mapped to the key `line.separator`. And we don't know *if* something has been received, because the `System.out.println` command is misplaced.

Comment: You hit the nail (the readline need to read a end of line char,if not it will keep waiting.But until now I don't know what is the "end of line char" is. I try /n /r /r/n /n/r and the System.getProperty("line.seperator"). Nothing work >.<. If I use in.read() I can get the message. But I need to get the message with the exact length (since there will be a checking on the length latter on)

Comment: I find it hard to imagine that `println()` would send something that isn't accepted by `readLine()`. But I agree that it is still bad idea to use `println()` as it's platform-dependent. Better to just choose some fixed separator for the protocol. Choosing `\n` is a good idea because `readLine()` will definitely work fine with it.

Comment: println() sends a line terminator and readLine() reads it. This is not the issue, and there is also no issue with println() being platform-dependent. readLine() will definitely work with with whatever it sends: specifically, \n, \r, or \r\n.

Comment: And the Javadoc doesn't say any such thing.