# Handler thread hanging on reading in

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to set up a server with a client and a handler. The client should ask for a string from the user. This should then be written to an OutputStream, get read in by the handler which then saves the string to its own OutputStream before passing it back to the client. I know that this program is completely pointless, I am just trying to get my head around how servers, clients and handlers work.

Here is my code so far:

Server

```
public class Server {
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    int port = 8080;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
      Socket client = server.accept();

      System.out.println("Client from "+client.getInetAddress()+" connected.");
      Handler handler = new Handler(client);
      handler.run();
    }
  }
}
```

Handler

```
class Handler extends Thread {
private Socket client;

public Handler(Socket c) {
    client = c;
}

public void run() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("1");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader in = 
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(),
                                                           "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("2");
        String message = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("4");

        System.out.println("5");
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
        client.close();
        System.out.println("Finish");

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

}

Client

```
public class Client {
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    Socket server = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    System.out.println("Attempting connection...");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a string:");
    String message = scan.next();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader in = 
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream(),
                                                       "UTF-8"));

    out.println(message);
    String messageReturn = in.read();
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Server said: " + messageReturn);
    in.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the handler seems to hang when it tries to read the message in. This problem seems similar to the one presented here: [Socket problem - readline won't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457975/socket-problem-readline-wont-work-properly)

But this solution isn't working for me. I have tried using objectInputStreams instead of my current solution, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried without "UTF-8"? And flushing could also help.

Comment: Just tried without "UTF-8", still no joy! I've added flushing to the end of Client now but that didn't help either...

Comment: Please post the real code. This does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether your client code will compile. The return type for this is int.

```
String messageReturn = in.read();
```

Anyway, this should work:

```
package network;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    Socket server = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9890);
    System.out.println("Attempting connection...");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a string:");
    String message = scan.next();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    out.println(message);

    // NOTE this
    String messageReturn = in.readLine();
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Server said: " + messageReturn);
    in.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

**Note** Port has been changed.

Server Output
Waiting for client...
Client from /127.0.0.1 connected.
1

Client Output
Attempting connection...
Please enter a string:
Hello

Comment: So all you changed was the port? I've done the same in my code and it made no difference! Not really sure how changing the port would make a difference anyway?

Comment: no, I have also added this to client.    String messageReturn = in.readLine();

Comment: Ahhh, sorry! And that works for you with the rest of my code? For some reason it still isn't working for me with that line!

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be that you do not send an escape sequence with your response. ReadLine() waits till it gets an escape. <s>Try sending a "\n" with your response.</s> There is an article about problems using readLine() and println() with sockets. It also shows how to solve it. 
[ReadLine() / Println() and sockets](http://test.javaranch.com/ulf/apple-java-tech-notes/Tech%20Notes/tn1157.html)

Comment: He is sending with println.

Comment: @Fildor http://test.javaranch.com/ulf/apple-java-tech-notes/Tech%20Notes/tn1157.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I've changed it to prevent errors in the future but it's not solving the current issue.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet Despite the fact that this is true - "you do not send an escape sequence" is not. println will send "some sort of" new line. I did not claim that it could not cause problems. Just wanted to point out that he is not "sending nothing".